# How to find exact match for search term in WP_Query? What is the additional string added in LIKE query in WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, query, search, mysql

While searching with the argument `s` it adds additional value before and after each Like query

`SELECT wp_7_posts.ID FROM wp_7_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (((wp_7_posts.post_title LIKE '{d146fc7cb41ff444163abadd50ac5da7ec5439fd51386c3cfe2cea107126703b}acetic{d146fc7cb41ff444163abadd50ac5da7ec5439fd51386c3cfe2cea107126703b}')`

Is there anyway to search exact term rather than searching word by word using WP_Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it adds additional value before and after each Like query

That `{d146fc7cb41ff444163abadd50ac5da7ec5439fd51386c3cfe2cea107126703b}` is a **placeholder escape string** for the literal `%` (percent) sign used in prepared statements (see [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)) and the escape string is generated by [`wpdb::placeholder_escape()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/placeholder_escape/).

So actually, that `{d146fc7cb41ff444163abadd50ac5da7ec5439fd51386c3cfe2cea107126703b}` is the `%` sign, but in an *escaped form*, and it will be *changed back* to `%` when WordPress sends the query to MySQL.

Therefore don't worry about that value; it' perfectly valid and added for a good reason.

> Is there anyway to search exact term

Yes, there is: Use the `exact` argument and set it to `1` or `true`. E.g.

1. In the browser, navigate to `https://example.com/?s=acetic&exact=1`.
2. Or in your template/PHP, run `new WP_Query( 's=acetic&exact=1' )`.

... and both the above will lead to WordPress searching for posts where for example the post title is exactly `acetic` and not `acetic acid`. I.e. The `LIKE` clause will not use the `%` sign as in `post_title LIKE 'acetic'` as opposed to `post_title LIKE '%acetic%'`.

Additionally, if you want to preserve spaces in the search keyword, wrap it with double quotes, i.e. `"<keyword>"`. So for example, if you had two posts titled `My foo bar baz post` and `My foo BAZ before bar post` respectively, then searching for `"foo bar"` would only match the first post which contains exactly `foo` followed by a space and `bar`, i.e. `foo bar`. But if you searched for `foo bar` (no quotes), then that would match both the posts because the title contains `foo` and also `bar`.

Also, the above `"<keyword>"` format is equivalent to setting the `sentence` argument to `1` or `true` as in `s=my foo&sentence=1`. But with the above format, you could further limit the search results, e.g. `my foo&sentence=1` would match both the above posts, but `"my foo", before` would only match the second post because it contains `before` *in addition to* `my foo`.

However, it should be noted that both `sentence` and the `"<keyword>"` format will use the `%` sign in the `LIKE` clause, so for an exact match without that `%` sign, use the `exact` argument.